# Getting an image from a list using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter, button

I have an list of images and what I want is for when I click a button, the image on the label changes from the previous or next one on the list. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *   

def left():
    dogImg = PhotoImage(file=dogList[index-1])
    index -=1
    dog.configure(image = dogImg)


def right():
    dogImg = PhotoImage(file=dogList[index-1])
    index += 1
    dog.configure(image = dogImg)


window = Tk()
window.configure(bg='dark turquoise')
window.geometry('500x700')

dogList = ['fox-terrier.png', 'afganHound.png', 'pug.png', 'bulldog.png']
index = 0    

dogImg = PhotoImage(file= dogList [index])
dog = Label(window, image = dogImg)

Left = Button(window, text='<-', command=left)
Right = Button(window, text='->', command=right)
    
Left.place(x = 250, y = 340)
dog.place(x = 280, y = 340)
Right.place(x = 320, y = 340)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: And what happens when you run this code?

Comment: You do have a bug, in that you have `index-1` in both functions.  You should increment/decrement index FIRST, then just use `index` in the PhotoImage call.  And you might want to check whether you've rolled off either end of your list.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work, all you have to do is make the variables inside functions global. This is because inside each function, `index` has scope inside that function, and when you declare them `global`, it affects the variables outside function scope.

```
def left():
    global dogImg, index                #global variables, else these will be treated as local inside this function
    if index==0:                        #base case, else error will be thrown when clicked left button on 1st picture
        return
    index -=1
    dogImg = PhotoImage(file=dogList[index])
    dog.configure(image = dogImg)


def right():
    global dogImg, index                #global variables, else these will be treated as local inside this function
    if index==len(dogList)-1:           #base case, else error will be thrown when clicked right button on last picture
        return
    index += 1
    dogImg = PhotoImage(file=dogList[index])
    dog.configure(image = dogImg)
```

Also, just a suggestion, when working with images in Tkinter, use Pillow package

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

Then you can open images like

```
dogImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(dogList[index]))
```